# Unable to suppress deprecation warnings

Tags: python, django

In my Django application, when I import one third party library, I get this warning in the console:

> the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses

If however I do the import inside Python shell, then everything is ok. I want to achive the same behaviour in Django. This is what I've tried based on answers in other OS threads:

```
import warnings
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango110Warning
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", category=RemovedInDjango110Warning)
```

The above code results in another error message, that says that RemovedInDjango110Warning does not exists. I also tried this:

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()

from third_party_lib import some_module
```

But still I get the very same error message. So, it seems like all previous answers to this problem got outdated. And we need some fresh fix. Thanks!

I also tried this:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=DeprecationWarning)
    from third_party_lib import some_module
```

But it has no effect.

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? Instead of just using importlib ?

Comment: The whole story is not about importlib. I'm using some library, that, perhaps, somewhere uses imp. And indeed I do not want to touch this library

Comment: I just want to suppress warnings as it is done by default in Python shell

Comment: Are you getting a `DeprecationWarning ` or `PendingDeprecationWarning`?

Comment: I get `PendingDeprecationWarning`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the code you've tried. If you want to filter `PendingDeprecationWarning`, then you should use `PendingDeprecationWarning` in your code. Your code is using `DeprecationWarning` and `RemovedInDjango110Warning`, which are different warnings. Secondly, the `fxn()` function in the docs is an example function that creates a warning. It doesn't make sense to include it in your code.

You can either filter all pending deprecation warnings

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=PendingDeprecationWarning)
```

However this might hide pending deprecations in your own code that you should fix. A better approach would be to use a context manager, to filter out warnings when importing the third-party lib.

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=PendingDeprecationWarning)
    from third_party_lib import some_module
```