# How to resolve "ImportWarning: can't resolve package from __spec__ ..." in Eclipse PyDev for ema_workbench?

Tags: python, eclipse, import, pydev, ema-workbench

I installed the ema workbench with

```
pip install ema_workbench
```

and would like to import some module:

```
from ema_workbench import Model
```

If I run this in Jupyter notebook or Spyder, it works fine. If I try to run this in Eclipse PyDev 7.1.0.201902031515 , I get following warning:

```
D:\EclipsePython\App\WinPython\python-3.7.1.amd64\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py:219: ImportWarning: can't resolve package from __spec__ or __package__, falling back on __name__ and __path__
  return f(*args, **kwds)
```

I thought that my PyDev settings for the Python Interpreter might be wrong. However, the ema_workbench is listed as installed package and the settings seem to be fine ?!

=>How can I fix that annoying warning?

=>Is this a PyDev issue or an issue of the ema_workbench (that is just not shown for Jupyter and Spyder??)

Related questions:

- [How to suppress ImportWarning in a python unittest script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51045319/how-to-suppress-importwarning-in-a-python-unittest-script)
- [Unresolved Import Issues with PyDev and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631377/unresolved-import-issues-with-pydev-and-eclipse)

[image]

*edit*

I tried to add

```
-W ignore:ImportWarning
```

to the "JVM Arguments" of the python run configuration.

I also tried to put following code on the beginning:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=ImportWarning)
```

Did not work...

Answer (score -5):

Too my knowledge it is an eclipse / pydev issue related to changes in the import system of python. Just google the message and see the many discussions related to it.

Comment: I created a corresponding PyDev bug ticket: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/986

Comment: I googled the message and this was the top result.  Goes to show that "Just google the message" is not a useful answer.