# How to run python code without the tensorflow warning

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tflearn

I am using python 3.6.9 and tensorflow 1.14.0 on windows 10 and have installed and updated all libraries on python 3.6. When I run my code I expect it to just print out the json data but instead I get a big tensorflow/tflearn error and I don't know why.

My code :

```
import nltk
import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json

from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()


with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)
```

Error I get :

```
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\summarizer.py:9: The name tf.summary.merge is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.merge instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py:25: The name tf.summary.FileWriter is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\collections.py:13: The name tf.GraphKeys is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py:123: The name tf.get_collection is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_collection instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py:129: The name tf.add_to_collection is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.add_to_collection instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py:131: The name tf.assign is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign instead.
```

What do I do to get rid of that error and run my code properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Numpy` will gonna deprecate some API. See the [release note](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#shape-1-fields-in-dtypes-won-t-be-collapsed-to-scalars-in-a-future-version).

> Shape-1 fields in dtypes won’t be collapsed to scalars in a future version
>
> Currently, a field specified as [(name, dtype, 1)] or "1type" is interpreted as a scalar field (i.e., the same as [(name, dtype)] or [(name, dtype, ()]). This now raises a FutureWarning; in a future version, it will be interpreted as a shape-(1,) field, i.e. the same as [(name, dtype, (1,))] or "(1,)type" (consistently with [(name, dtype, n)] / "ntype" with n>1, which is already equivalent to [(name, dtype, (n,)] / "(n,)type").

But your `tensorflow` version uses [(name, dtype, 1)] and it cause the deprecation warning. Since it is warning, you can just ignore and later `tensorflow` version or latest will take care about this warning.

This is already implemented into `tensorflow` package, [see this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/3402d7118460857cf484f57338d14d9113597d15). Please update package to the latest, it will resolve the issue I think.

One more thing is that the `tflearn` package also have deprecated commands. It is again used in the `tensorflow` package but since `tflearn` package is not active recently, I think you have to ignore this warning, that will not be resolved. See [the repository](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn).

Comment: is there a way to ignore/delete those warnings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993553/unable-to-suppress-deprecation-warnings might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14.0

pip install numpy==1.16.4
```